# Implement transaction commit listener using fabric-sdk-node v2.1

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am currently using version `2.1` of `fabric-sdk-node` and trying to implement transaction commit listener in the application using `Network.addCommitListener()` function however I am not able to receive any event after submitting a transaction for endorsement.

For implementing this, I have used below code:

```
var listener = (error, event) => {
            if (error) {
                // Handle peer communication error
            }
            else {
                // Handle transaction commit event
            }
        };

        const peers = network.channel.getEndorsers();
        await network.addCommitListener(listener, peers, txId);
```

It seems there is some issue with the `listener` object because as per the [official documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/master/module-fabric-network.Network.html#addCommitListener__anchor), type of listener object is defined as `CommitListner`, but not able to figure out how to implement that here in my solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to receive commit events from all peers in the network then you can achieve this by simply using the `NETWORK_SCOPE_ALL_FOR_TX` default transaction event handler. Everything else is taken care for you and all calls to `Transaction.submit()` will return only after commit events have been received from all contactable peers.

If you want to implement your own custom commit waiting logic instead of using one of the default implementations, you should implement your own transaction event handler. This will be invoked at an appropriate time during the submit flow and passed the information you need.

The above two approaches are described in detail on this page, including a link to a sample transaction event handler implementation (which uses a commit listener) at the bottom of this page:

- https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/master/tutorial-transaction-commit-events.html

A final approach, which I would recommend only for more advanced scenarios where you really need to submit transactions as fire-and-forget and asynchronously manage your own handling of transaction commit events, is to grab the transaction ID and attach a commit listener **before** calling submit to ensure that you don't miss the transaction commit event. The submit should then be carried out with a `NONE` transaction event handler so the submit returns immediately after the transaction is successfully sent to the orderer. This requires at least version 2.1.1 of *fabric-network* where the ability to get the transaction ID in advance of the call to submit (and to override the default transaction event handler per transaction) is introduced.

All of the patterns above should also be possible in the v1.4 release but the event listening API was slightly different. See here for more details:

- https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-transaction-commit-events.html
- https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-listening-to-events.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I am also following third approach by submitting a transaction using `NONE` strategy, but still not able to receive any transaction event in the `listner` callback function. I have mentioned the code for my `listner` in the question.